# Java unchecked call vs Kotlin in Android LiveData

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm developing my own LiveData extension.

I'v decided to do it in java.

My code:

```java
public class LiveEvent<T> extends LiveData<T> {

    @Override
    public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {
        // unchecked!
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(observer);
        super.observe(owner, observer);
    }

    public class Wrapper<V> implements Observer<V> {
        private final Observer<? super V> mObserver;

        Wrapper(final Observer<? super V> observer) {
            mObserver = observer;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(V v) {
            //todo
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: `Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(observer);` is Unchecked call.
However, in kotlin, it looks pretty good:

```java
class LiveEvent<T> : LiveData<T>() {

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        val wrapper = Wrapper(observer)
        super.observe(owner, observer)
    }

    inner class Wrapper<T> internal constructor(private val mObserver: Observer<in T>) : Observer<T> {

        override fun onChanged(t: T) {
            //todo
        }
    }
}
```

So, i have several questions:

1. How can i improve my Java code to make it safe?
2. Is kotlin wildcards really safe, because kotlin do not have *raw* type? Or they just, sort of, don't show warnings?
3. And finally, is it a good idea to develop android libraries in 2019 on java?

Comment: I have this weird feeling that your Wrapper reimplements `MediatorLiveData`.

Comment: Not really. There is a lot of code actually. I just made it simpler for the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i improve my Java code to make it safe?

You got everything right except `new Wrapper(observer)` gives you a raw type in Java. You need to specify the generic type:

```
Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<>(observer);
```

This will make the warning go away, all types now match.

Other than that your Kotlin code and Java code are equivalent. You dont have to specify the generic type in Kotlin because it infers the type from `observer` (and you don't have to explicitly type variables).

> is it a good idea to develop android libraries in 2019 on java?

Your third question is opinion based so don't expect an answer here on Stack Overflow.